# Generic Action Link in MVC 3 / Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Just started a new MVC 3 project and I can't get the strongly-type generic action link and url helpers I am used to in MVC 2 futures.

Which nuget packages and namespaces do I need to get hold off?

Example

```
Html.ActionLink<HomeController>(c => c.Index(), "Home")
```

ANSWER:

Just needed to reference Microsoft.Web.Mvc via NuGet MvcContrib - and make the namespace available in the views.

Comment: you will need to provide us with a bit more info. Whats not working?

Comment: Do you have some examples of what you were using from the futures project?

Comment: Example of strongly-typed generic action link now added for those who don't know what they look like.

Comment: @nick check this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584673/html-actionlink-and-html-displayfor-at-the-same-time-not-right-but-it-descri)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Which nuget packages and namespaces do I need to get hold off?

- Official NuGet **Mvc3Futures** package is **[here](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Mvc3Futures)**
- Namespace to declare is **Microsoft.Web.Mvc**

Answer (score 3):

Grab the T4MVC package in NuGet.

Comment: Don't think these are the ones I mean't. I've posted an example of one from the futures package I was referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Just need to reference Microsoft.Web.Mvc