# Is Generic Controller Action Possible To Do?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, parameterized

If so, how can I call it from my View?

The controller action that I have in mind is something like this:

```
public ActionResult UrunYonetimi<T>(int param = 0)
{
   // doing stuff
}
```

Can we have an action like this? If so, how can I specify that `T` from my e.g `@Url.Action()` call?

Comment: Is There a particular reason about it?. Could you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: I have polymorphism regime going on in my models. I mean my models inherit from a base class, and I'd like to use the same action for different types, if possible. The controller action will use the base type

Comment: Base on your answer, why you just received the Parent class as a parameter in the Action? and then do the cast to the corresponding child

Comment: I can do a conditional block, using `if(obj is something)` fashion, yes. But this way would look cooler I guess, for querying purposes.

Comment: Well I readlly don't know if it's possible, but let's wait if someone know's the answer

Comment: Well I tried to call the action without much preparation, it gave me this error: **Cannot call action method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult UrunYonetimi[T](Int32)' on controller 'Controllers.YoneticiController' because the action method is a generic method.**

Comment: take a look to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028744/generic-action-link-in-mvc-3-razor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've come to an understanding for this issue:

I guess we need to declare our nice generic functions in the model rather than in the controller, and handle different types from there. We can and *probably should* have different actions and thus different URLs for every model type, but they will all call the same function from the model, only with different types.